# Как правильно поменять сцену в живых обоях

Tags: java, android, libgdx

**Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении настроек, сцены менялись и работали без проблем?**

В обоях в настройках можно выбрать 2 сцены, с танком и автобусом. В классе AndroidLauncher прописано

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new AutoRender(), config);

}
```

и класс AutoRender:

```
class AutoRender implements ApplicationListener {

float screenOffset;
boolean settings_changed_flag = false;

private Tank tank = new Tank();
private Bus bus = new bus();
int character;

@Override
public void create() {

    if (character == 1)
        tank.create();
    if (character == 2)
        bus.create();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void render() {

    if (character == 1)
        tank.render();
    if (character == 2)
        bus.render();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}
}
```

при таком коде, при переключении сцен, выскакивает ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(float)' on a null object reference
```

в самих обоях в превью выходит надпись что приложение остановлено, но потом сцена загружается и все работает как надо. *Если изменить метод create() класса AutoRender:*

```
@Override
public void create() {
tank.create();
bus.create();
}
```

то сцены переключаются моментально без ошибок, но сцена с tank уже не реагирует на нажатия.

А если оставить как было, и добавить

```
@Override
public void resume() {
    this.resume();
}
```

то обои при звонке или блокировке перезагружаются..

**Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении настроек, сцены менялись и работали без проблем?**

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то получается следующее: в первом случае при переключении Вы начинаете рендерить сцену без ее создания, поэтому и возникает ошибка NullPointerException. Во втором случае сцена с tank не реагирует на нажатие скорее всего потому что в методе create() вызывается Gdx.input.setInputProcessor() и получается что на ввод всегда будет реагировать только bus.

Comment: Это я понимаю, просто не хватает знаний, какой метод использовать. Мне кажется нужно прописать что то в методах resume(), pause()...

Comment: resume() и pause() тут не при чем. Нужно создать метод changeCharacter(int character) в AutoRender и уже в нем при изменении сцены освобождать ресурсы текущей сцены и создавать новую.

Comment: Звучит просто и логично, но у меня не получается это реализовать. Если можно, напишите хотя бы небольшой фрагмент кода, я не нашел примеров в сети.

Comment: Для начала в Tank и Bas нужно создать метод setInput() и в него перенести весь код отвечающий за регистрацию ввода. Полагаю что Вы используете Stage, поэтому нужно прописать Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage). Далее создайте метод AutoRender.changeCharacter(int newCharacter) { if(character == newCaracter) return; if(newCharacter==1) { character=1; tank.setInput(); } else if(newCharacter==2) { character=2; bus.setInput(); } }. И в Вашем случае придется создавать tank и bus сразу, т.е. AutoRender.create() { tank.create(); bus.create(); }. Думаю должно быть так, поскольку полного кода я не видел.

Comment: Не знаю как вас благодарить!)) Спасибо Вам большое, что подсказали верное направление. Добавьте его в Ответ, я отмечу, что он верный. Спасибо!